# JTable show all Records (Data), just in one column?

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, jtable

In the Code the JTable retrieves all Data from a Database with one Table and two Columns.

The program is just a minimal Example. Database (Javadb) "SOMETABLE" , Table "TESTTABLE" , Column one "DATA1" (char) , Column two "DATA2" (char) .

The program gets and shows the input and records from and to the command line. The rest is done on the Gui. First get the Inputs for DATA1 and DATA2, then click Save, then show the records by clicking Load.

And then click Del, to show the records on JTable. Just switching between GUI and CLI.

But when I execute the program, the JTable shows all Data just in one Column, instead of the two Columns ?

Sorry for misunderstandings.

```
public class DBtest {
    JFrame f;
    JPanel p1;
    JPanel p2;
    JPanel p3;
    JButton b1;
    JButton b2;
    JButton b3;
    JMenuItem delete;
    JPopupMenu pm;
    JTable t;
    String[] c = {
        "DATA1",
        "DATA2"
    };
    Object[][] obj = null;
    Object o1;
    Object o2;
    int n;
    Scanner sc;
    String s1;
    String s2;
    Object row2Delete;
    Connection con;
    PreparedStatement ps;
    Connection con1;
    PreparedStatement ps1;
    Connection con2;
    PreparedStatement ps2;
    Connection con3;
    PreparedStatement ps3;
    ResultSet rs;
    ResultSet rs2;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new DBtest().startApp();
    }

    public void startApp() {
        p1 = new JPanel();
        p2 = new JPanel();
        p3 = new JPanel();
        b1 = new JButton("Save");
        b1.addActionListener(new SaveListener());
        b2 = new JButton("Load");
        b2.addActionListener(new LoadListener());
        b3 = new JButton("Del");
        b3.addActionListener(new DelListener());
        t = new JTable(obj, c);
        pm = new JPopupMenu();
        delete = new JMenuItem("Delete ?");
        delete.addActionListener(new DeleteListener());
        pm.add(delete);

        p1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        p1.add(p2, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        p2.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        p2.add(b1);
        p2.add(b2);
        p2.add(b3);

        f = new JFrame();
        f.getContentPane().add(p1);
        f.setTitle("Database");
        f.setSize(450, 550);
        f.setResizable(false);
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Type something");
        s1 = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Type again");
        s2 = sc.nextLine();
        sc.close();
    }



    public class DelListener implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
            try {
                tableView(); //filling the table
                boolean DEBUG = false;
                boolean ALLOW_COLUMN_SELECTION = false;
                boolean ALLOW_ROW_SELECTION = true;

                t.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500, 70));
                t.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
                t.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
                if (ALLOW_ROW_SELECTION) {
                    ListSelectionModel rowSM = t.getSelectionModel();
                    rowSM.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
                        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
                            if (e.getValueIsAdjusting()) return;
                            ListSelectionModel lsm = (ListSelectionModel) e.getSource();
                            if (lsm.isSelectionEmpty()) {
                                System.out.println("No rows are selected");
                            } else {
                                int selectedRow = lsm.getMinSelectionIndex();
                                pm.show(t, 50, 50);
                                System.out.println("Row  " + selectedRow + " is now selected");
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
                JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(t);
                p1.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                f.validate();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(DBtest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(DBtest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

        }
    }
    public void tableView() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {

        Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver");
        con1 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/TESTTABLE", "me", "1234");
        con1.commit();
        String sql = "SELECT DATA1 FROM ME.SOMETABLE";
        ps1 = con1.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs = ps1.executeQuery();

        con2 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/TESTTABLE", "me", "1234");
        con2.commit();
        String sql2 = "SELECT DATA2 FROM ME.SOMETABLE";
        ps2 = con2.prepareStatement(sql2);
        rs2 = ps2.executeQuery();

        //Create new table model
        DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel();

        //Retrieve meta data from ResultSet
        ResultSetMetaData metaData = rs.getMetaData();
        ResultSetMetaData metaData2 = rs2.getMetaData();
        //Get number of columns from meta data
        int columnCount = metaData.getColumnCount();
        int columnCount2 = metaData2.getColumnCount();
        //Get all column names from meta data and add columns to table model
        for (int columnIndex = 1; columnIndex <= columnCount; columnIndex++) {
            tableModel.addColumn(metaData.getColumnLabel(columnIndex));
        }
        for (int columnIndex = 1; columnIndex <= columnCount2; columnIndex++) {
            tableModel.addColumn(metaData2.getColumnLabel(columnIndex));
        }
        //Create array of Objects with size of column count from meta data
        Object[] row = new Object[columnCount];
        Object[] row2 = new Object[columnCount2];
        //Scroll through result set
        while (rs.next() && rs2.next()) {
            //Get object from column with specific index of result set to array of objects
            for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++) {
                row[i] = rs.getObject(i + 1);
                for (int h = 0; h < columnCount2; h++) {
                    row2[h] = rs2.getObject(h + 1);
                }
            }
            //Add row to table model with that array of objects as an argument
            tableModel.addRow(row);
            tableModel.addRow(row2);
        }

        //Now add that table model to your table
        t.setModel(tableModel);
        t.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
    }




    public class DeleteListener implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
            try {
                Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver");
                con3 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/TESTTABLE", "me", "1234");
                con3.commit();
                String sql = "DELETE FROM ME.SOMETABLE WHERE DATA1=?";
                int row = t.getSelectedRow();
                int column = t.getColumnCount();
                for (int i = 0; i < column; i++) {
                    row2Delete = t.getValueAt(row, i);
                }

                ps3 = con3.prepareStatement(sql);
                ps3.setString(1, "+row2Delete+");

                int rowsDeleted = ps3.executeUpdate();
                System.out.println("Row deleted: " + "  " + rowsDeleted);
                if (rowsDeleted > 0) {
                    System.out.println(" delete successfully!");
                }
                ps3.clearParameters();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(DBtest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(DBtest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (ps3 != null) con3.close();
                    if (con3 != null) con3.close();
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(DBtest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class SaveListener implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
            try {
                Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver");
                con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/TESTTABLE", "me", "1234");
                con.commit();
                //System.out.println(textAreaText() + "\n");
                String sql = "INSERT INTO SOMETABLE (DATA1, DATA2)" + "VALUES (?,?)";
                ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
                ps.setString(1, s1);
                ps.setString(2, s2);
                ps.executeUpdate();
                ps.clearParameters();
            } catch (SQLException es) {
                es.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (ps != null) con.close();
                    if (con != null) con.close();
                } catch (SQLException se) {
                    se.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class LoadListener implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
            try {
                Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver");
                con1 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/TESTTABLE", "me", "1234");
                con1.commit();
                String sql = "SELECT DATA1 FROM ME.SOMETABLE";
                ps1 = con1.prepareStatement(sql);
                rs = ps1.executeQuery();

                con2 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/TESTTABLE", "me", "1234");
                con2.commit();
                String sql2 = "SELECT DATA2 FROM ME.SOMETABLE";
                ps2 = con2.prepareStatement(sql2);
                rs2 = ps2.executeQuery();
                ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();

                while (rs.next() && rs2.next()) {
                    for (int z = 0; z < rsmd.getColumnCount(); z++) {
                        n = z + 1;
                        o1 = rs.getObject(z + 1);
                        o2 = rs2.getObject(z + 1);
                        System.out.println(rs.getObject(z + 1) + "\n");
                        System.out.println(rs2.getObject(z + 1) + "\n");
                    }
                }
                ps1.clearParameters();
                ps2.clearParameters();
            } catch (SQLException es) {
                es.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception ex) {} finally {
                try {
                    if (ps2 != null) con2.close();
                    if (con2 != null) con2.close();
                    if (ps1 != null) con1.close();
                    if (con1 != null) con1.close();
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(DBtest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to pull data from two different tables?

Comment: No, one table and two columns.

Comment: Why two different queries?

Comment: I'm sorry I misunderstood something. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `tableView` method makes no sense.  Why are you opening two connections to the data, running two different queries on the same table and then trying to merge them?

You're also risking leaking your resources (leaving database connections open), which isn't going to be healthy in the long run.

The simple answer to the question is, use SQL properly.  Query the database for the columns you want from the table you want in as few statements as possible.  For example...

```
public void tableView() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver");

    //Create new table model
    DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel();

    try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/TESTTABLE", "me", "1234")) {
        String sql = "SELECT DATA1, DATA2 FROM ME.SOMETABLE";
        try (PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql)) {
            try (ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()) {
                ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
                int columnCount = rsmd.getColumnCount();
                List<String> columnNames = new ArrayList<>(columnCount);
                for (int column = 0; column < columnCount; column++) {
                    columnNames.add(rsmd.getColumnName(column + 1));
                }

                tableModel.setColumnIdentifiers(columnNames.toArray(new Object[columnNames.size()]));

                while (rs.next()) {
                    Object row[] = new Object[columnCount];
                    for (int column = 0; column < columnCount; column++) {
                        row[column] = rs.getObject(column + 1);
                    }
                    tableModel.addRow(row);
                }
            }
        } finally {
            t.setModel(tableModel);
        }
    }
}
```

Also take a look at [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) for a better way to manage your resources...